# Why Python Requests HTTP library always return sent cookies?

Tags: python, python-requests

Using python shell

```
>>> import requests
>>> cookies = {'sentcookie':'666'}
>>> res = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page', cookies=cookies)
>>> res   
<Response [200]>
>>> res.cookies
<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[Cookie(version=0, name='sentcookie', 
value='666', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='', domain_specified=False, 
domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=None,  
discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HttpOnly': None}, rfc2109=False)]>
>>>
```

Why is 'sentcookie' included in the cookies list returned from the server? I've sniffed the communication and no cookie is returned from the server. 
Why does requests include it in the list and how can I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the exact same problem and I don't think I fully understand your answer.
Assuming you want to add cookies to your request according to the documentation
this is the right way to do that:

```
cookies = {'sentcookie':'666'}
response = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page', cookies=cookies)
```

Now if the server returns cookies you can access them by:

```
response.cookies
```

But I don't expect to get the same cookies that I have sent even if the server didn't returned them, for some reason it's happening.

How I can to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Just updated my request version from 0.14.2 to 1.0.3 and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about *disabling* the behaviour, you're *telling* `requests` **to do that** behaviour.

In this:

```
cookies = {'sentcookie':'666'}
res = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page', cookies=cookies)
```

You're telling it you want that cookie to be available, whether it's needed or not...

You normally use `cookies=` for existing cookies you may have from a browser cache or something (for some reason) and just leave `requests` to handle cookies from the server as per normal

Comment: I'm telling 'requests' to send the 'cookies' dictionary to the server with the HTTP request. For some reason 'requests' also put this cookie in the HTTP response dictionary AS IF it was sent from the server, but it was not sent from the server.

Comment: @OdedGolan No - but it was still in the cookies that you told it to set - so why shouldn't it be there?